# multidimensional array store each list array inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have nested multidimensional arrays that may be 2 or 3 levels deep. Inside it I may or may not have list arrray. I need to loop over the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => cat_name_1
            [list] => Array
                (
                    [1] => swgdgbdg
                    [2] => xcbcxb
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => cat_name_3
            [list] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => cat_name_1
                            [list] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => 543h54h
                                    [2] => 54hrhhfr2
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => cat_name_2
                            [list] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => eherfherh
                                    [2] => 4564642
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => erggb45yt
                            [2] => jyuk768k
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => sdgsdgsdg
                            [2] => 4tg34g34g
                        )

                )

        )
```

and store the following in another array:

```
        array (
  0 => array ( 
      [1] => swgdgbdg
      [2] => xcbcxb
  ) ,
  1 => array(
      [1] => 543h54h
      [2] => 54hrhhfr2
  ) ,
  2 => array(
      [1] => eherfherh
      [2] => 4564642
  ),
  3 => array(
     [1] => erggb45yt
     [2] => jyuk768k
  ),
  4 => array(
     [1] => sdgsdgsdg
     [2] => 4tg34g34g
  )

);
```

Comment: We are not here to solve your homework!!! What have you tried?

Comment: i wish it was my homework i have try foreach and isset and i cant get it to work

Comment: try recursion too

Comment: It appears this data is being pulled from some sort of database. Perhaps a better solution would be to normalize the data (make the data all formatted the same)

Comment: i cant its a json that come from anther source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array_walk_recursive() to get the key 1,2 and are not array element, like this, check the **[live demo here](https://eval.in/816735)**.

```
$result = [];
$temp = [];
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k) use(&$result, &$temp){
if($k == 1)
  $temp[$k] = $v;
if($k == 2)
{
  $temp[$k] = $v;
  $result[] = $temp;
}
});
print_r($result);
```

Edit for unfixed length and unordered index, **[live demo.](https://eval.in/816734)**

**Extend the array_walk_recursive() with a third parameter for the callfunction to indicate if it's at the start of an subarray.**

```
$result = [];
$temp = [];
$length = 0;
uarray_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k, $f) use(&$result, &$temp, &$length){
if(is_numeric($k)) {
  if($f && $length != 0) {
    $result[] = $temp;
    $length = 0;
    $temp = [];
  }
  $temp[$k] = $v;
  $length++;
}
});
$result[] = $temp;
print_r($result);


function uarray_walk_recursive(&$input, $funcname)
{
    if (!is_callable($funcname)) {
        if (is_array($funcname)) {
            $funcname = $funcname[0] . '::' . $funcname[1];
        }
        user_error('uarray_walk_recursive() Not a valid callback ' . $user_func,
            E_USER_WARNING);
        return;
    }

    if (!is_array($input)) {
        user_error('uarray_walk_recursive() The argument should be an array',
            E_USER_WARNING);
        return;
    }

    $args = func_get_args();
    $flag = true;

    foreach ($input as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $args[2] = false;
            $flag = true;
            uarray_walk_recursive($item, $funcname, $args);
            $input[$key] = $item;
        } else {

            $args[2] = $flag;
            $flag = false;
            $args[0] = &$item;
            $args[1] = &$key;
            call_user_func_array($funcname, $args);
            $input[$key] = $item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thankk but i can have a 10 arrays inside a array not only 3 and its a random order i may have array on 4 postion and in another array its can be on the 8 postion

Comment: @shlomicohen `array_work_recursive()` is recursive funciton. Also works for your 10 situation.

Comment: but i may have the nasted array in 4 postion or 8 not only 1-2

Comment: if length is fixed, for example `(1-n)`, just a small modification will do.

Comment: not fixed i have 60 arrays inside the main array and each is anther nustetd array with random length

Comment: @shlomicohen you can check it now

Comment: thaks! but its only working when the array with array inside is a 1 postion it can be on any postion

Comment: @shlomicohen you can check my answer now.

Comment: @KrisRoofe You are genius man!! I learned something new for me in php. Because the logic you used was beyond my knowledge, now I have one more logic in collection.;) It will help me in future!. Thanks (y)

Comment: @shlomicohen you need to do your homework, if you don't know how to use my code. Just pay some efffort, you will run it. Sorry, I cannot any more for you.

Answer (score 0):

PseudoCode

```
function getSomething(var arr)
{
   flag = 0;
   output = []
    for( i = 0 to arr.length)
    {
      check arr[i] is array, 
      if yes,then  flag = 1 and output.add(getSomething(arr[i]))
      if not, continue 
    }
  if flag =0,then return arr
  else return output;
}
```

Comment: @shlomicohen you have to just replace pseudo code with some functions

Comment: how can i run it?

Comment: hey @shlomicohen,  just write the code with this logic